# Java: is there a way to construct a max-heap from an array in O(n) using PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the PriorityQueue(Collection c) constructor will create a min-heap from a collection in time O(n). However, I couldn't find a constructor where I can pass both a collection and a comparator (in order to convert the min-heap to a max-heap). So I was wondering if  there is a way to construct a max-heap from an array (say, int array) in O(n) using PriorityQueue?

Comment: Not currently, no, though I've seen some discussion threads on core-libs-dev discussing adding it.

Comment: This new constructor is not added yet. I think this will be a good enhancements to the PriorityQueue class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, having a set of elements arranged in a min-heap does not provide any advantage for rearranging them into a max-heap.  Also, you seem to be assuming that the `PriorityQueue` constructors that accept a collection have `O(n)` asymptotic complexity.  That's plausible -- even likely -- but it is not documented, so it is not safe to rely on it.